# GUI JButton, how to assign buttons(which are questions) to answers

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

ok so i just need a simple answer/hint/advice or maybe if you guys are feeling generous to fix my java GUI code.

So basically my problem is in this game is when the user answers one of my questions, he/she can get it right, but, there is a major flaw where the user can use any answer from any of my question to get it right.

IK I made it that way, but i dont know how to do it any other way! I did some research on this and i couldnt find anything on google because i dont even how to word this question, so i came to a forum like this in hopes of getting some hints or answers.

And no i dont expect anyone to change anything, just looking for some answers to understand what to do!

CODE:

```
public void init () //method name init
 {
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (6,0));

    //set component fonts
    Font titleFont = new Font ("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 35);
    Font otherFont = new Font ("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 35);

    //gives a title for program
    lblTitle = new JLabel ("GEOGRAPHY JEOPARDY", JLabel.CENTER);
    lblTitle.setFont (titleFont);

    //use color constant to set colour
    lblTitle.setForeground (Color.blue);
    lblTitle.setLocation (0,0);

    //makes the intro empty for now
    lblIntro = new JLabel ("");
    //gives the label a font
    lblIntro.setFont (otherFont);

    //the buttons are initialized and contains strings to be compared in action listener
    btn1 = new JButton ("Question 1, 100 points");
    btn2 = new JButton ("Question 2, 200 points");
    btn3 = new JButton ("Question 3, 300 points");
    btn4 = new JButton ("Question 4, 400 points");
    btn5 = new JButton ("Question 5, 500 points");
    btnCheck = new JButton ("Check answer");


    //sets the text to nothing
    txtInput = new JTextField ("", JTextField.CENTER);
    //gives the text in textbox a font
    txtInput.setFont (otherFont);


    //add actionListener to buttons
    btn1.addActionListener (this);
    btn2.addActionListener (this);
    btn3.addActionListener (this);
    btn4.addActionListener (this);
    btn5.addActionListener (this);
    btnCheck.addActionListener (this);

    //makes the label info empty
    lblInfo = new JLabel ("", JLabel.CENTER);

    //Split button into 2 seperate buttons
    panelButtons = new JPanel (new FlowLayout ());
    panelButtons.add (btn1);
    panelButtons.add (btn2);
    panelButtons.add (btn3);
    panelButtons.add (btn4);
    panelButtons.add (btn5);
    panelButtons.add (btnCheck);


    //the items to add on the panel
    pane.add (lblTitle);
    pane.add (lblIntro);
    pane.add (panelButtons);
    pane.add (lblInfo);
    pane.add (btn1);
    pane.add (btn2);
    pane.add (btn3);
    pane.add (btn4);
    pane.add (btn5);
    pane.add (btnCheck);
    pane.add (txtInput);



       }
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {


    //which buttons are  being pressed
    String command = event.getActionCommand();
    //if statements regarding what happens when the buttons are clicked 
    if (command.equals("Question 1, 100 points"))
    {
      //set the text to blank
      btn1.setText("");
      //set the label with the question
      lblInfo.setText(q1);

    }
    //if this button is clicked...
    else if (command.equals("Question 2, 200 points"))
    {
      //set the text empty
      btn2.setText("");
      //display question 2
      lblInfo.setText(q2);
    }  
    //if this buttton is clicked...
    else if (command.equals("Question 3, 300 points"))
    {
      //empty text 
      btn3.setText("");
      //show question 3
      lblInfo.setText(q3);
    }
    else if (command.equals("Question 4, 400 points"))
    {
      //make button 4 text empty to indicate that it has been already picked
      btn4.setText("");
      //show question 4 in the label called info
      lblInfo.setText(q4);
    }
    //the action listener is lisening for this button to be clicked
    else if (command.equals("Question 5, 500 points"))
    {
      //make emtpy
      btn5.setText("");
      //display question 5
      lblInfo.setText(q5);
    }         
    else 
    {

    } 
    //listening for that button
    if (command.equals("Check answer"))
    {
      //the textfield is equal to the variable input
      input = txtInput.getText();
      //***THE PROBLEM***
      if (input.equals(a1)||input.equals(a2)||input.equals(a3)||input.equals(a4)||input.equals(a5))
      {
        //if the user input is equal to the answer do...
        if (input.equals(a1))
        {
          //say its correct
          lblIntro.setText("Corect!");
          //display it in green colour
          lblIntro.setForeground (Color.green);
          //give user 100 points
          points = points + 100;
          //display points
          lblTitle.setText("You have: " + points);
        }
        //if the user input is equal to the answer do...
        else if (input.equals(a2))
        {
          //say its correct
          lblIntro.setText("Corect!");
          //display it in green colour
          lblIntro.setForeground (Color.green);
          //give user points
          points = points + 200;
          //display the points on panel
          lblTitle.setText("You have: " + points);
        }
        //if the user input is equal to the answer do...
        else if (input.equals(a3))
        {
          //correct answer
          lblIntro.setText("Corect!");
          //set green colour-
          lblIntro.setForeground (Color.green);
          //give points for correct answer
          points = points + 300;
          //display those points
          lblTitle.setText("You have: " + points);
        }
        //if the user input is equal to the answer do...
        else if (input.equals(a4))
        {
          //say the user is correct
          lblIntro.setText("Corect!");
          //show it in green
          lblIntro.setForeground (Color.green);
          //give points for reward
          points = points + 400;
          //show on title
          lblTitle.setText("You have: " + points);
        }
        //if the user input is equal to the answer do...
        else if (input.equals(a5))
        {
          //say he or she is correct
          lblIntro.setText("Corect!");
          //make the text to display it in green
          lblIntro.setForeground (Color.green);
          //give them points for their efforts
          points = points + 500;
          //display the points awarded
          lblTitle.setText("You have: " + points);
        }
      }
      // if any other answer is given
      else 
      {
        //say they are incorrect
        lblIntro.setText("Incorrect!");
        //right it in red
        lblIntro.setForeground (Color.red);
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since this is a GUI question, you should probably include some screenshots of what's happening and what you want to have happen - the text description doesn't exactly give a clear picture of what you want to do. And we can't really test it ourselves since you didn't give us a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which you should always do).

Comment: The English part of your question does not tell us anything about the issue you are facing. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The answer needs to be associated with the question (sounds obvious)...

What you could do is keep the answer and question in some kind of `Map`, this would allow you to loop up the answer based on which ever question was active.

```
private Map<String, String> mapQA;
private String currentQuestion;

//...

mapQA = new HashMap<>(4);
mapQA.put(q1, a1); // Or how ever you want to do it...
//...

if (command.equals("Question 1, 100 points"))
{
    //set the text to blank
    btn1.setText("");
    //set the label with the question
    lblInfo.setText(q1);
    currentQuestion = q1;

}
//if this button is clicked...
else if (command.equals("Question 2, 200 points"))

//...

if (command.equals("Check answer"))
{
    //the textfield is equal to the variable input
    input = txtInput.getText();
    String answer = mapQA.get(currentQuestion);
    if (answer.equals(txtInput.getText()) {...
```

Now, if it was me, I would be probably also associate each question with each `JButton`...

```
 Map<JButton, String> mapButtons;

 //...
 btn1 = new JButton ("Question 1, 100 points");
 //...     
 mapButtons = new HashMap<JButton, String>(4);
 mapButtons.put(btn1, "..."); // Question 1...
```

This way, you could simply use...

```
JButton btn = (JButton)event.getSource();

//set the text to blank
btn .setText("");
//set the label with the question
currentQuestion = mapButtons.get(btn)
lblInfo.setText(currentQuestion);
```

And do away with the `if` statements, except the "check answer" button ;)